# CollectionChanged event of observablecollection in c#

Tags: c#, events

How can write this code better:

```
void CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ObservableCollection<PromotionPurchaseAmount>)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            foreach (PromotionPurchaseAmount item in e.NewItems)
            {
                //Removed items
                item.PropertyChanged -= EntityViewModelPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (PromotionPurchaseAmount item in e.NewItems)
            {
                //Added items
                item.PropertyChanged += EntityViewModelPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (sender is ObservableCollection<PromotionItemPricing>)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            foreach (PromotionItemPricing item in e.NewItems)
            {
                //Removed items
                item.PropertyChanged -= EntityViewModelPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (PromotionItemPricing item in e.NewItems)
            {
                //Added items
                item.PropertyChanged += EntityViewModelPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (sender is ObservableCollection<PromotionItem>)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            foreach (PromotionItem item in e.NewItems)
            {
                //Removed items
                item.PropertyChanged -= EntityViewModelPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (PromotionItem item in e.NewItems)
            {
                //Added items
                item.PropertyChanged += EntityViewModelPropertyChanged;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What specifically are you looking for? Does the code not work properly? Perhaps this would be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: helped me, not sure why it was closed.

Comment: helped me too, I don't think it was too localized.

Answer (score 6):

1. When `e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove` you need to iterate over `e.OldItems` instead of `e.NewItems`.
2. When `e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace` you need to iterate over `e.OldItems` to remove the event handler from the old items and you need to iterate over `e.NewItems` to add the event handler to the new items.
3. Refactor the code like this:

   ```
   if (sender is ObservableCollection<PromotionPurchaseAmount> || 
       sender is ObservableCollection<PromotionItemPricing> || 
       sender is ObservableCollection<PromotionItem>)
   {
       if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove ||
           e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
       {

           foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.OldItems)
           {
               //Removed items
               item.PropertyChanged -= EntityViewModelPropertyChanged;
           }
       }
       if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add ||
           e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace)
       {
           foreach (INotifyPropertyChanged item in e.NewItems)
           {
               //Added items
               item.PropertyChanged += EntityViewModelPropertyChanged;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

This works, because all of your Promotion classes implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: What about if items are replaced? Shouldn't the event handler be removed then as well?  How does that work?

Comment: You need to remove that "else" brotha. And from what I've read since I wrote my comment, replace is when the setter of the indexer is used.  so a third option is probably better. ;)

Comment: @Jordan: You are right about the `else`. Fixed that. However, you don't need a third option.

Comment: if (e.OldItems != null)
            {
                foreach (ODataQueryClauseViewModel item in e.OldItems)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged -= XXXChanged;
                }
            }

            if (e.NewItems != null)
            {
                foreach (ODataQueryClauseViewModel item in e.NewItems)
                {
                    item.PropertyChanged += XXXChanged;
                }
            }